# Display a graphic in report with sweave : Just display the final report and no intermediate file

Tags: r, latex, sweave

I know R well but I start in Sweave.

I produce a report under Rstudio from several scripts:

- **graphic.R** which defined a graphic created with ggplot2 called *graph_1*. I want to display it in the report.
- **script.Rnw** containing Latex and Sweave code. I call *graph_1* to display my graphic.
- **main.R** script that executes the .Rnw code and therefore produces the report.

**In graphic.R**

```
library(ggplot2)
graph_1 <- ggplot(data=iris, aes(x = Sepal.Length, y = Sepal.Width)) + geom_point(aes(color=Species, shape=Species))
```

**In script.Rnw**

```
\documentclass[french,12pt]{article}
\begin{document}

 ... no important...

\begin{figure}[h]
  \begin{center}
   << fig=TRUE, echo=FALSE, height = 2.5>>=
    graph_1
    @
 \caption{caption figure 1}
 \label{graph_1}
  \end{center}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

**In main.R**

```
Sweave("script.Rnw", encoding="UTF-8")
tools:::texi2dvi(file="script.tex"), pdf=TRUE)
```

Everything is OK : my report (.pdf) is generated in the folder. But I also have a file : 'script-001.pdf' containing my graphic which is added in the same folder.

I would like only the final report and not  the intermediate file : so not the file 'script-001.pdf'.
Somebody know if it is possible ?

Thank you,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The figure file is required so that LaTeX can include it. But you can delete it safely after running Sweave and LaTeX.

I don't like my working directory to be littered with intermediate PDFs, too. So I have them end up in a folder called `figures`. With Sweave you can accomplish this by setting a suitable prefix:

```
\SweaveOpts{prefix.string=figures/fig}
```

You also need to create the `figure` folder yourself for it to work.

And a personal recommendation: You may want to have a look at [knitr](https://yihui.name/knitr/) – it's a more powerful modern version of Sweave – in  my opinion.